# How to deal with few subjects leaving the study in the sample?

Tags: sampling, sample

I am having moving population. As in everyday new subscribers are getting added in the population and few are leaving my subscription service.

Sample I take on starting period of the study, from that sample few subscribers will leave the study. For these subscribers, I won't have data getting generated once they leave. How will I address this issue?

Comment: What is the population?

Comment: @BradS. The population being subscribers to an online entertainment service.

Answer (score 0):

**Before edit of the question**

your approach may not be the best bet at arriving at a solution. You don't know if the subscribers moving out are representative of the population or not. So I would like to suggest something different but it should be an apt method in you case.

This approach is basically taking a representative population and then seeing who are the ones moving out. Take a sample of the population using simple random sampling from the population. And if you want to figure out some knowledge about the fellow subscribers leaving the service you can track the individuals in the sample which you got previously.

**After edit in the question:**
It will depend on the objectives of the study if it is really required to get the data generated for the subscribers who have left the service. The question is yet unclear about that. But I will try answering:

To get the data generated once the subscribers leave, you need to do some kind of experimental trial on the sample you take from the population. You can then do your analysis over the data generated for the two groups i.e. those who have left and those who haven't. This seems to be a pretty expensive option.

Comment: I have edited my question